# Is document.referrer cross browser compatible?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

I'd like to use document.referrer for an informal referrer check. Is this element cross browser compatible? Will any browser throw an error when trying to reference the document object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `document.referrer` property is described in the DOM spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140

So it **should** be supported cross-browser. However, you can easily detect if the implementation does support this property like

```
if( 'referrer' in document ) { 
    console.log(document.referrer);
}
```

Comment: just on the side, be careful when testing browser support using console.log as itself is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can not depend on it to determine if the request is coming from a browser (many non-browser robots also send one). While it is supported by browsers their are also privacy programs to specifically not provide it. Sometimes this is done by a proxy server ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer ... and If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to a non-secure connection, then the referrer field is not sent.

So the answer is yes but with exceptions.

Comment: I think you're referencing the server side `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`  header value and not the javascript `document.referrer`

Answer (score -3):

Yes. It is supported by major browsers. see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Comment: even if this is true, I wouldn't rely on anything from the site `w3schools.com`.

Comment: Here's a slightly more credible source confirming the same thing, so I think maybe w3schools.com is right on this one. http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/DocumentReferrerProperty

Comment: Thanks guys. I never thought that w3schools provide inaccurate data.

Comment: amusingly, to support your comments.. their example doesn't work when referred from this page.