# How to find website refer using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I find which website referred to the my website using Javascript? For exmaple, if A.com had a link to B.com (my website), how could I tell who referred to my website?

Thanks

Comment: which recently referred?

Comment: If A.com had a link to B.com, how could I tell on B.com how the curent user came to my website (B.com)? This question was answered below. I was not aware of the document.referrer javascript variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [`document.referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer) to retrieve this information.

Comment: Thanks! Does this run the same on all browsers? Will I need to use jQuery?

Comment: Yes, runs the same in all browsers. It is a DOM Level 2 property. No need for jQuery.

Comment: @user1530249 that will tell you that a user saw the page prior to visiting your site it will not tell you whether there's a link on that page

Comment: @RuneFS Do you have documentation on this? I'm pretty sure the referrer must have a link on it's page. If a visitor accesses your page without clicking a link, the referrer property will be empty. Under certain conditions it will also be empty when a visitor did click a link to your page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097808/is-document-referrer-cross-browser-compatable

Comment: Basically, if the information exists, you can access it with that property. pretty straight forward. If it's not in that property, you can't get it.

Comment: @Jacco depends on your definition of "link" I meant it as an anchor. If that's the definition then the statement is true. Setting document.location affects document.referrer when the page is refreshed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems like a very obvious thing once it is known but I really had no idea it was so simple.